# @babel/traverse - getting deepest node at offset

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to add some custom auto completions in a vscode extension I'm writing.

In order to do that, I need to understand the AST node at the current caret position.
I'm using @babel/parser and @babel/traverse for this.
In this example below, I'm looking for an `ImportSpecifier` at a given offset in the code.
Using the if statement (`offset >= path.node.start && offset <= path.node.end)` seems very hacky to me.

Is there a better option to get the **deepest** node at a specific offset?

```javascript
const code: string = ...
const offset: number = ...

const ast = parser.parse(code, {
  errorRecovery: true,
  sourceType: 'module'
})

traverse(ast, {
  ImportSpecifier: path => {
    if (offset >= path.node.start && offset <= path.node.end) {
      resolve(true)
    }
  },
  exit: path => {
    if (path.type === 'Program') {
      resolve(false)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Why do you think it's hacky?

Comment: Hi @FelixKling , It's hacky because I need to know the type of the node ahead of time (in this example it's `ImportSpecifier`.
I simply want to get the deepest node at a position, no matter what it is.